# Query string to firestore Angular - multiple choices

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating an application in Angular with Firestore database.
I have to do a query with different selection parameters.

How can I make a string so that the query changes depending on the user's selection?

The application has a selection form with the following fields:

```
Date from
Date Until
status
Client
Seller
paymenttype
```

There are multiple possible combinations and the idea is to build a string with the fields that have been selected

For example:

In .ts

```
if (typeof this.staTus != "undefined" && typeof this.paymenttype != "undefined" && typeof this.Client != "undefined" && typeof this.Seller != "undefined") {

  strquery = '"order", ref => ref.where("DateOrder", ">=", "' + this.Datefrom + '").where("DateOrder", "<=", "' + this.DateUntil + '").where("idclient", "==", "' + this.Client + '").where("status", "==", "' + this.staTus + '").where("seller", "==", "' + this.seller + '").where("paymenttype", "in", "' + this.paymenttype + '").orderBy("DateOrder", "desc").limit(5000)';

  this.orderServices.getOrdersRep(strquery).subscribe(ord => {
    this.Ped_ = ord;
  })
}
```

In services

```
  getOrdersRep(strq?) {
    this.ordersColletionrep = this.db.collection(strq);

    this.ordersrep = this.ordersColletionrep.snapshotChanges().pipe(map(changes => {
      return changes.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Order;
        return data;
      })
    }));
    return this.ordersrep;
  }
```

In this way there is no error but it does not work for me, it does not bring the data

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

**ts**

```
if (typeof this.staTus != "undefined" && typeof this.paymenttype != "undefined" && typeof this.Client != "undefined" && typeof this.Seller != "undefined") {

  const query = (ref: CollectionReference) => {
    return ref.where("DateOrder", ">=", this.Datefrom )
      .where("DateOrder", "<=", this.DateUntil)
      .where("idclient", "==", this.Client)
      .where("status", "==", this.staTus)
      .where("seller", "==", this.seller)
      .where("paymenttype", "in", this.paymenttype)
      .orderBy("DateOrder", "desc")
      .limit(5000);
  };

  this.orderServices.getOrdersRep(query).subscribe(ord => {
    this.Ped_ = ord;
  })
}
```

**service**

```
getOrdersRep(query) {
  this.ordersColletionrep = this.db.collection("order", query);

  this.ordersrep = this.ordersColletionrep.snapshotChanges().pipe(map(changes => {
    return changes.map(a => {
      const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Order;
      return data;
    })
  }));
  return this.ordersrep;
}
```

Comment: fine, it works for me that way, but I need to make the query change depending on the selection. can you help me with this?

Comment: I guess you also need to modify your html. Please provide your html.